# Como bloquear botão submit após o envio do form AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso bloquear o meu botão submit para que o formulário não seja enviado mais de uma vez. Segue código:

- Arquivo JS:

  ```
       $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           //Receber os dados
           $form = $(this);                
           var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);

           //Criar a conexao com o servidor
           var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

           //Progresso do Upload
           request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
               var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
               $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
           });

           //Upload completo limpar a barra de progresso
           request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
               $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('envio concluído!');
               //Atualizar a página após o upload completo
               setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 1000);   return false;
           });

           //Arquivo responsável em fazer o upload do arquivo
           request.open('post', 'controller/licencaController.php?acao=arquivo');
           request.send(formdata);


       });
  ```
- Arquivo HTML (PHP):

  ```
  <html><form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input required class="multiplo" accept=".<?= $info_upload['formato'] ?>" type="file" name="arquivo">
    <div style="height: 25px; margin-top: 4px" class="progress progress-striped active">
                       <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;">
                       </div>
                   </div>
    </center>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_resp" class="btn btn-success upload">Salvar arquivo</button></form></html>
  ```

Vocês conseguem me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue código (script JS) corrigido:

```js
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

//Adiciona este trecho:
                    $(":button").click(function() {
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    });     

// Fim do trecho.       

        //Receber os dados
                    $form = $(this);    
                    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);
                    
                    //Criar a conexao com o servidor
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    
                    //Progresso do Upload
                    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                        $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
                    });
                    
                    //Upload completo limpar a barra de progresso
                    request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
                        $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('envio concluído!');
                        //Atualizar a página após o upload completo
                        setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 1000);   return false;
                    });
                    
                    //Arquivo responsável em fazer o upload do arquivo
                    request.open('post', 'controller/licencaController.php?acao=arquivo');
                    request.send(formdata);
                    
                
                });
```